# What is the Big O notation for Standard Deviation and Interquartile Range (IQR)?

Tags: big-o

I want to know the time complexity for calculating the Standard Deviation and Interquartile Range (IQR).
Please correct me If I am wrong, the Standard Deviation requires O(n),
while the IQR requires O(n log n).
I appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: Depends a bit. Time complexity in terms of what operations? Do you assume constant-time addition and multiplication?

Comment: I know that Stdv requires iterating through the dataset twice to calculate the average and the variance. And even though IQR is based on finding the median, the dataset must be sorted in advance. In my opinion, the sorting part makes IQR more time complex than the Stdv.

Comment: Right, yes your thinking is correct but it can actually be done faster. See my answer below :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To calculate the standard deviation, you need iterate through the dataset twice, as you say (once for the mean, once for the element-wise deviation). This gives you a time complexity of *O(2n) = O(n)* arithmetic operations.

For IQR, you need to find the quartiles Q1 and Q3. As you say, you can achieve this by sorting the data (*O(n log n)*) and then accessing them directly. But you can do this faster by using the [Quickselect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect) algorithm instead, and get the quartiles in *O(2n) = O(n)* average time.

Notice that I am talking about time complexity with respect to arithmetic operations here. The actual time complexity can be higher if your values are unbounded and you have to take into the account the complexity of multiplication and addition as well.